# Decouple frontend from backend, what JS framework/library to use?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, reactjs, web-frontend

I want to full decouple frontend from backend of an existing site, The site currently uses [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) and cookies (jinja2/python).

After reading many options, [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) and [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) js seem to be a way to go, but I would like to know/have some feedback about what could be the best for this task and also easy to maintain in the future years.

So far If I understand properly **React** is only a VIEW library, and I will need something extra for pulling/posting data, whereas **Angular** is a full framework.

I will be using [json tokens](http://jwt.io/) and JSON for POST/GET data between the backend REST API, Angular seems to be the option for this, but for rendering and updating the Views React seems to do a nice job.

I was thinking on using [polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/), but seems to be only compatible with chrome, and at least I would like to support Safari, Firefox, no worries about IE.

I would like to avoid using both or end building a heavy page, for now I plan to use [purecss](http://purecss.io/) but still need to find what could be a best JS library/framework to use.

So before continue searching, googling, I would appreciate any idea, tip or comment.

Comment: is it large application?

Comment: If it's a small application, you can use ReactJS in conjuction with jQuery AJAX functionality.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil "opinion-based" and "which framework should I use" are both close reasons at Programmers, same as Stack Overflow. Please read: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/22815)**.

Comment: @Snowman Oh, well then I guess it doesn't have its place on any SE site?

Comment: Depends upon to you because, if your existing project is large and your team is well to known in various javascript library. Then you can use angularjs

Comment: Indeed, this is off-topic on most SEs. Sorry, because it's well-formed. But the Help Centre is quite clear that we do not allow resource/library/software/tool recommendation questions here. However, there is hope! It doesn't even seem like a good fit for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. Consider joining one of our chat rooms and asking in that format.

Comment: Hi, it may be a tricky question but that's exactly the issue I am facing, even after searching, I found to many  different opinions/comments that confuse me a little more, that's why I wanted to give a try here and simple ask, The project/page is similar to gmail (custom messaging frontend) blog, CMS and planing to use websockets for new features like chat/etc, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely things  are changing very fast, after doing more research, chatting via IRC with people using lot of many frameworks and with more experience, I decided to go for [react js](https://facebook.github.io/react/).

At the end frontend is all about views, and I would like the easy, simple way to handle/maintain this.

For doing the POST/GET calls we will just use vanilla AJAX.

Comment: For POST/GET calls you can also use Fetch, which is supported by newer versions of chrome natively already. For the other browsers you can use a polyfill in the meantime. So down the road, you won't have to rely on anything except vanillaJS supported by all browers.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to be "that guy" but after spending many hours using Angular (1, not 2x) and a few hours with React, I keep falling back to [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) (data binding/view) and [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) (ajax) for most web app front ends. They're just so darn simple.

Throw on a lightweight API backend with [Falcon](http://falconframework.org), [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org), [Pycnic](http://pycnic.nullism.com), etc, and development feels very clean.

I guess my point is: I wouldn't rule out the time-tested and still maintained tools. Angular and React may not last as long, though I think both will do everything you need.

If you do decide to go with React, then you might be interested in its TypeScript (tsx) implementation as well. The [VS Code](http://code.visualstudio.com) editor supports this well with intellisense -- I was pleasantly surprised.